# Why the vector $(\nabla f(a), -1)$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane at the point $(a, f(a))$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-analysis, 3d, plane-geometry

I can't see very clearly why the following scalar product is true:

$\langle (\nabla f(a), -1),  v \rangle = 0$

where $ f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ and $ v \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ is a vector collinear to the tangent plane at the point $(a, f(a))$.

I already know that the gradient is perpendicular to the level curves, but I don't see how to use this information.

I need a conceptual explanation (a proof by computation is well-appreciated too).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function (on $\Bbb R^3$) defined by 
$$
G(x, y, z) = z - f(x, y)
$$

How is the level surface $G = 0$ related to the graph of $f$?

What does the gradient-perpendicular-to-level-sets theorem tell you about this level surface?

Comment: The level surface G = 0 corresponds to the level surfaces at all z, I see that if we take z = f(a), we have the level curves which at point (a, f(a)) are collinear to the tangent plane. But why is there a "-1" in (∇f(a),−1), and how to extend the gradient to $  \mathbb{R}^3 $ ?

Comment: "The level surface G = 0 corresponds to the level surfaces at all z." That statement makes no sense to me; I think you really need to go back and answer that question very explicitly. When you've answered it, you'll be somewhat closer to a final result. In fact, I'm going to suggest that you consider a particular $f$, namely $f(x, y) = x^2 + 3y$, draw the graph of $f$, find a tangent vector to that graph at the point $(1, 2, 7)$, etc.

Comment: I would mean at a particular z, when z is fixed.

Comment: It still makes no sense.